# Regex matching background-url not working Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari

Given the format of background url's is normally url("http://foo.com/picture.jpg"), I've been using regex to extract the URL from between the quotation marks. However I found this wasn't working on Safari and couldn't figure why. This was my code:

```
var currentBg = $('#featureImage').css('background-image');
var url = currentBg.match(/(["'])(\\?.)*?\1/)[0];
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why is that when you access the 'background-image' property on Safari at least on my ipad, it doesn't store the URL in strings, it's simply url(http://foo.com/image.jpg), so the regex wasn't matching.

I modified my regex to capture whats between the brackets and replace any quotes with ''

```
str.match(/\((.*?)\)/)[1].replace(/('|")/g,'');
```